# Parse promise is never run inside _.each()

Tags: javascript, loops, parse-platform, promise

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.limit(500);
if(helpers.isDefined(userSkip)){
    userQuery.skip(userSkip);
}

var userCount = 0;

userQuery.find().then(function (users) {

    _.each(users, function(user){
        console.log("Got user " + user.get("displayName"));

        var viewHistoryQuery = new Parse.Query("ViewHistory");
        viewHistoryQuery.equalTo("user", user);

        viewHistoryQuery.find().then(function(){
            console.log("Got here");
        }).then(function(){
            console.log("View History success");
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("View History error");
        });
        userCount++;
    });

})
.then(function () {
    status.success("Processed " + userCount + " users");
}, function (error) {
    status.error(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

`Got here` is never printed to the console. The only output I get is:

```
I2015-08-24T15:04:03.424Z]Got user #####
I2015-08-24T15:04:03.424Z]Got user #####
Input: {}
Result: Processed 500 users
```

Got user is printed multiple times, I just hashed out the username. Doesnt really make much sense. The promise should be running inside the _.each loop and the thenable should be printing one of the messages. It acts as if it doesnt exist. We know that the users are being looped and accessed, but the next promise is being ignored.

Comment: Afaik, `then` does not take three arguments?

Comment: You are quite right. I've updated the code to be correct now, but it doesnt seem to have corrected the main problem. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: You are aware that `_.each` does not automagically wait for any promises created in it? After the queries are started, you immediately increment the `userCount` and go to the next. `Got Here` would log after your "processed 500 users". Maybe `status.success` does cancel all ongoing queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating promises but is not waiting for them to resolve. Promises "wait" based on return value: if you return a promise from a `then` it will wait for it before continuing on to the next part of the chain:

```
emptyPromise().then(function(){
    return wait(1000); // the fact we return a promise from here is what causes it to wait
                       // remove the return and it will log done instantly
}).then(function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

In your code the function with the `each` does not return anything - so nothing is waited.

```
userQuery.find().then(function (users) {

    // this is a _.map so we get return values
    var ps = _.map(users, function(user){    
        var viewHistoryQuery = new Parse.Query("ViewHistory");
        viewHistoryQuery.equalTo("user", user);
        // We return here
        return viewHistoryQuery.find().then(function(){
            console.log("Got here");
        });
        userCount++;
    });
    // https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#.when
    return Parse.Promise.when(ps); // return a when call for all promises
}).then(function(results){
    console.log("All Done here");
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I had considered passing the promises to when() but figured that the promises would simply execute and Id have to deal with them after the next then(), therefor losing my link with the user. Thanks for explaining this.